# Generic specification in chained method call

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public static <T> Foo<T> newFoo() {
        return new Foo<>();
    }

    public Bar<T, T> toBar() {
        return new Bar<>(this, new ArrayList<T>());
    }
}

public class Bar<S, T> {
    public Bar(Foo<T> Foo, List<S> list) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<Integer> newFoo = Foo.newFoo();
        Bar<Integer, Integer> s = newFoo.toBar();
        Bar<Integer, Integer> s2 = Foo.newFoo().toBar();
    }
}
```

The first two lines of the main method work fine. The last line (`Foo.newFoo().toBar()`) gives me an error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Bar<Object,Object> to Bar<Integer,Integer>`. Is there a way to this in one line without getting an error? Casting to `Bar<Integer, Integer>` doesn't work.

More out of curiosity than necessity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
Bar<Integer, Integer> s2 = Foo.<Integer>newFoo().toBar();
```